# Custom Keyboard on iOS doesn't trigger "Editing Changed" Event

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, editing

I have created a custom keyboard that is kind of working fine. It changes the values in the textField, but it doesn't trigger the Sent Event "Editing Changed".
If I use the computer keyboard or the regular IOS keyboard, the event is triggered and the function assigned to it is called.

So, the textField data is changed, but it doesn't recognize it as an "Editing Changed".
The method textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: is also not being called.

Any idea?

Comment: have u set delegate UITextFieldDelegate into .h file

Comment: Yes. The custom keyboard shows up and it's working; when I use it it changes the text in the UITextField but it doesn't trigger the event. If I input data through the custom keyboard and press the (X) button in the UITextField to clean it, the event is triggered...
The textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: method also is not triggered.